# How to compare 2 classifiers using a classification metric?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, model-evaluation, accuracy, auc

Let's assume we have 2 binary classifiers (A and B) and some labeled dataset, and we want to compare A and B. Let's assume we use the ROC AUC as the metric (although it could be the accuracy or something else, it should not matter).

What is the best way to compare A and B?

- split the data into a training set and test set. Train A and B, and compute the AUC on the test set. The highest value wins.
- Compute the average AUC of A and B by cross-validation. The highest value wins.
- Compute the mean and the variance of the AUC by cross-validation (or collect the AUC obtained for each CV fold). Apply some statistical testing (which one?)

Comment: Of likely interest: [Benavoli, Alessio, et al. "Time for a change: a tutorial for comparing multiple classifiers through Bayesian analysis." The Journal of Machine Learning Research 18.1 (2017): 2653-2688.](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume18/16-305/16-305.pdf) This article promotes Bayesian methods but goes through alternatives (granted, alternatives that the authors believe to be inferior to their approach).